# JQuery Form Plugin include submit button's value?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm just trying out the JQuery form plugin as such:

```
$("#my-form").on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function (e) {
            if (!$("#my-form").valid()) { //if form is invalid, show errors and don't submit
              e.preventDefault();
                return;
            } 
else {
        $("#my-form").ajaxSubmit(); 
            return false;

    }
        });
```

The ajaxSubmit() method is not submitting the value of the submit button clicked to my processing page. I know I can get the value like this `formaction= + $(this).attr("value")` so how do I add this to the form submission.

Comment: Add a hidden input to your form, and copy the submit button's value to it.

Comment: @volumeone Can you try '$(this).ajaxSubmit();`

Comment: @VishalPatel that won't work because it will try to submit the button clicked not the form. i've made it work now using the answer given by jack

Comment: @volumeone Thank you for the updates... Also thanks Jack to improve my knowledge also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api), `ajaxSubmit` takes zero or one argument. The single argument can be either a callback function or an [Options Object](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object).

Therefore, something like:

```
$("#my-form").ajaxSubmit(data: { formaction: this.value });
```

should work.

Comment: nice thanks. it didn't quite work as per your example, but when i added it to an options object it worked flawlessly. cheers!